# como usar el preg_replace en php en este caso?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

alguien de casualidad tiene los conocimientos de como usar la instrucción preg_replace?
en mi caso tengo esta etiqueta:

```
<a class="btn btn-naranja btn-lg" style="color: white; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px;" 
 href="https://mienlace.com/marcas/">buscar</a>
```

pero solo quiero modificar o remplasar parte de la estructura del el enlace que esta en el href por ejemplo a esto "https://mienlace.com/autos/marcas/" para que quede asi:

```
<a class="btn btn-naranja btn-lg" style="color: white; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px;" 
 href="https://mienlace.com/autos/marcas/">buscar</a>
```

Comment: Faltan detalles en tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, ¿por qué quieres hacerlo en PHP cuando es un elemento del cliente y se podría hacer mejor en Javascript, modificando directamente el `href` si fuera necesario?

Comment: hola @A.Cedano que tal, lo que pasa que no lo hago con javascript por que el boton no tiene id, tampoco tiene nombre, solo es un boton que se agrega desde el editor de wordpress cosa que ya esta en varias paginas que utilizan un template de wordpress donde hago filtros de contenido, entonces no tendria la idea si por javascript se puede alterar la url ya que esos botones no tienen id tampoco name